# Team Explorer Visual Studio 2015 missing Exclude

Tags: visual-studio-2015, team-explorer

I updated VS2015 to update 2.

After that the option to Exclude from commit disappeared.

http://prntscr.com/appnym

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caught me out too. It's been replaced by Staging   https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx#teamexp

Comment: Tks... is this! =]